# Mysql duplicating rows dynamically at runtime based on columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine the following table structure:

**appointments**

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | test1 |
|  2 | test2 |
|  3 | test3 |
+----+-------+
```

**appointment_carers**

```
+----+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
| id | appointment_id | carer1 | carer2 | carer3 |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |              1 |      1 |      2 |      3 |
|  2 |              2 |      4 |      5 |      6 |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Unfortunately there's no much I can do now to change the existing structure of these tables.

Is there a way I can query all appointments and for every carer slot I get a duplication of the appointment row?

Here is an example of the intended result of the query:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | carer |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | test1 |     1 |
|  1 | test1 |     2 |
|  1 | test1 |     3 |
|  2 | test2 |     4 |
|  2 | test2 |     5 |
|  2 | test2 |     6 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Unpivot `appointment_carers` table and JOIN result with `appointments` table

Comment: Yes, google for `union`

Comment: I think a schema redesign is in order. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: I'm aware of the flaw in the schema, thank you for the heads up though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `union all`:

```
select a.id, a.name, ac.carer
from ((select ac.id, ac.appointment_id, ac.carer1 as carer
       from appointment_carers ac
      ) union all
      (select ac.id, ac.appointment_id, ac.carer2 as carer
       from appointment_carers ac
      ) union all
      (select ac.id, ac.appointment_id, ac.carer3 as carer
       from appointment_carers ac
      )
     ) ac join
     appointments a
     on ac.appointment_id = a.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, name, carer from (
select appointment_id, carer1 as carer from appointment_carers
union
select appointment_id, carer2 as carer from appointment_carers
union
select appointment_id, carer3 as carer from appointment_carers
) as carers
join appointments on id = appointment_id;
```